# Microsoft Teams Chatbot checklist

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, teams-toolkit

I'm completely new in the microsoft teams application world. I would like to build a teams chatbot which should be able to work as a checklist. So the bot should be able to tell which task are done and some task should be completed by the Bot automatically trough API calls others are just a yes or no question to check if you're done with the task. Further Task should only be possible if the previous task is done. So the Bot should be able to edit and safe the task objects and Task 2 to Task n should be blocked todo while task 1 is still open.

Where do I store the task information eg(id,name, description, status(open,done,in progress) and in which form so the Teams Bot can edit and overwrite the status. Is it possible to do this with a JSON? Or doesn't make this any sense?

Comment: @E X 0 D Ij A -Please have a look at this doc- https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-todo
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-create
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/teams/authoring-first-bot-teams
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: @E X 0 D Ij A - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?